# Creating Python Azure Function in Visual Studio 2015 doesn't auto-create "Python Environments" file

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-functions

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and have downloaded the Python Azure Functions tools and have been following [this documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/) on creating a Python Azure Function (the docs show the creation of a C# function, but I chose "Python" in the dropdown menu).

However, I created the function app and function and don't see a Python Environments file:

What I'm seeing:

[image]

The Python Environments file I want:

[image]

Thus, my questions:

1. What do I need to do to get the Python Environments file to show up?
2. How can I install an external library to my Azure Function environment? (This one: https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is similar to the answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0eec433c-863c-4017-b63c-9d50f2051fcc/issues-with-sqlalchemy-on-python-azure-functions?forum=AzureFunctions

To copy it here:

> Virtual environments are not supported with the Functions v1 runtime.
>
> Refer to the link below to learn how to install a custom version of
>   Python and use third party modules with it -
>
> https://ourwayoflyf.com/running-python-code-on-azure-functions-app/
>
> Make sure the version of sqlalchemy you're installing is compatible
>   with your version of Python installed.
>
> Please note that this feature is currently 'experimental' and we don
>   not recommend or support it for production scenarios. We're currently
>   working on first-class Python support for the v2 runtime which will
>   make this scenario a lot easier -
>   https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker